# Unexpectedly non-nil pointer in C array in Objective-C code

Tags: objective-c, arrays

Below is the code

```
Thing *thingA = [[Thing alloc] init];

thingA.name = @"paper";

Thing   *things[0];
things[0] = thingA;

NSLog(@"%@", things[0].name);
// output paper

[thingA release];
// here dealloc on Thing class is call

NSLog(@"%@", things[0].name);
// output paper yet
- Here I thought that this object would be nill
```

Why is the element things[0] that points to thingA pointer not nil, thus making the application crash? Why was thingA pointer not nil?

Comment: Why are you doing this? As far as I can tell, there's no guarantee that `things[0]` will exist after you've released `thingA`, since `thingA` is going to be deallocated real soon.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C array in Objective-C maintains pointer to object already deallocated](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5124715/c-array-in-objective-c-maintains-pointer-to-object-already-deallocated)

Answer (score 1):

If I remember right, Objective-C will not release the memory if there are still other objects/variables referencing that location.

However, it is crashing because your array Still has the memory location address which no longer is available for referencing and thus crashing when you try to acces with thing[0].name

Hope this helps.

Comment: An object is released when its `retainCount` hits zero.

Comment: That's right but one has to manually increase that count if I recall right to avoid memory deallocation.

Comment: The question in the code example show that the things[0].name had the state the thingA pointer when thingA already deallocated. the last statement still show "paper". I think that thingA after the [thingA realease] had to assign to nil.

Answer (score 1):

You're right in thinking that the memory for `thingA` has already been deallocated by the time execution reaches the final `NSLog` statement, but there's no guarantee that the operating system has marked it as invalid at that point. Since the value you placed at that address is still there, and `thingA` is still a pointer to that value, the `NSLog` statement still works.

The operating system doesn't automatically set local variables to `nil` if the memory they refer to gets deallocated. That's one of the reasons pointer variables can be dangerous. If you like, you can programmatically set these variable to `nil` yourself after sending a `release` message, particularly if there's any chance they will be used again in the same block of code.