# C array in Objective-C maintains pointer to object already deallocated

Tags: objective-c, arrays

From the code:

```
Thing *thingA = [[Thing alloc]init];
// thingA pointer reference 0x00998

Thing *things[] = {thingA};

[thingA release];
// release method of the Thing class correctly invoked

thingA = nil;
// thingA pointer reference now is 0x0

NSLog(@"%d", things[0]);
// odd, because things[0] still maintains the pointer reference 0x00998
```

Why does the element `things[0]` maintain the pointer reference `0x00998`?
In the moment that `thingA` goes `dealloc` through `release` and after to set to `nil` (the reference to `thingA` now is `0x0`) how `things[0]` still the reference to `0x0998`?
I thought that `things[0]` pointer would look with `0x0`.

Answer (score 4):

Line `thingA = nil;` affects only `thingA` reference. It doesn't affect any other reference or object itself.

You can make this example a bit simpler

```
Thing *thingA = [[Thing alloc]init];
Thing *thingB = thingA;

[thingA release];
thingA = nil;

// thingA is nil, but thingB still has old reference
```

Note, that since object itself is released, you shouldn't use `thingB` reference: memory it points to may be used for something else already.

Comment: Thing *thingB = [thingA retain];  Would allow you to keep using B after releasing a?

Comment: @Mark In a way. `retain` call will increase 'retain count' to 2 and `release` call will decrease it back to 1. But you can't release A and B separately: they are references pointing to the same object. I.e., there're two references, but only one object. And in your example it won't be released. You can check the [docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html) for details.

Comment: The thingB can exist even wrong same i not set thingB to nil?

Comment: @Tortuo Yes, that's the kind of problems you have without garbage collection. You may store reference to some object, but object was already released and OS has reused its memory for something else. Naturally, calling it will result in crash.

Comment: @Tortuo You may be already familiar with it, but [official apple guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/MemoryMgmt.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000011-SW1) is a good place to get started with memory management in objective c.